# Limit User to 1 Like/Dislike per Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iteration

I have a listing model (which allows comments) and users can like (thumbs up) or dislike (thumbs down) the listing. It works at the moment but I want to iterate over the likes for a specific listing, and if any like's user_id `listing.likes.user_id` matches the current users ID `current_user.id` then remove the form to like (users can add a reason why they are liking the listing)

```
<%= form_for([@listing, @listing.likes.build]) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %> 
<%= f.text_field :body %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I have something halfway there that checks if the current likes user_id matches the current user id, if so provide a link to delete (remove/unlike) the like.

```
<% if current_user.id == like.user_id %>
<%= link_to '[ Delete Like ]', [like.listing, like],
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
           <% end %>
```

How would I go about using the code to remove the like form if the user has already created a like/if the user's ID matches the `user_id` of a like created for a specific listing(something like this?)

```
<% if current_user.id == listing.likes.any.user_id %>
<% else %>
<%= form_for([@listing, @listing.likes.build]) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %> 
<%= f.text_field :body %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had the right idea with the `any` method, but were not using it correctly. `any` can accept a block in which you can do your `user_id` comparison, like so:

```
<% if listing.likes.any{|like| like.user_id == current_user.id } %>
```

In this case, `any` will return true the instant the condition in the block evaluates to true.

Let me know whether this works.

**Side Note**

If my method works for you, you may like to further clean up your view code by moving that check in to the `Listing` model as a helper method. Something like this:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ... other stuff

    def has_comment_from?(target_user)
        likes.any{|like| like.user_id == target_user.id }
    end
end
```

And then you can simply call it from the view like so:

```
<% if listing.has_comment_from? current_user %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a partial solution but it stops the user from commenting after 1 comment, not 1 comment per listing.

```
<% @listing.likes.each do |like| %>
    <% if current_user.id == like.user_id %>
    <% else %>
        <%= form_for([@listing, @listing.likes.build]) do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
            <%= f.text_field :body %>
            <%= f.submit %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not a fan of indentation then? ;-)

Comment: Is that better? The editor I am using does not perform indentation and (still new to programming in general) not sure if there is a set standard for all languages, or if each language has different indentation? (used other text editors that have had an option to "set indentation" but list 10 + languages)

Comment: @Aluxzi Did a minor indentation fix for you. Seems like SO doesn't like mixing tab and space characters when it comes to formatting. Just curious, I assume the empty `if` block is where that link you mentioned would go (you just omitted it for brevity), correct?

Comment: Thank you, I noticed the fix it came up in my notifications. The "solution" i posed doesn't quite work. The answer to your question is yes. My current solution doesn't quite work, it allows a user to post 1 comment, not one comment on each individual listing. I was trying to make it so if the current user had already posted a comment, the comment form would be removed. I know I need to iterate over each comment and match the user id to the comment's user_id but do not know the code to do so.